# How to use WKWebView with local file in appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I tried to use the new WKWebview with a local URL for appcelerator

```
var WK = require('ti.wkwebview');

var webview = WK.createWebView({
    url:'about.html',
});

win.add(webview);
```

My about.html file is in the root folder, and the HTML code is :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px">
<p align="center"><img src="images/DefaultIcon.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" border="0"></p>
<p align="center"><b>Text to test thanks</p>
<br/>
</html>
```

But the page does not displayed. I don't understand why. Any idea ?

Comment: Dan, why are you using this still? I was about to show you how I load local HTML but then realized you are using this module instead of the built in default WebView component.

Starting with SDK 8.0.0.GA WKWebView is used as the default WebView component. So if you're using SDK 8.0.0.GA or higher you can use Ti.UI.createWebView() on Classic or <WebView> on Alloy and you can drop WKWebView Module.

Comment: @Newport99 You have to use WKWebView for iOS now. UIWEbView are no longer accepted : itms 90809

Comment: Dan we are saying the same thing...except the module has not been updated in 2 years - stop trying to use it. 
 
With Titanium SDK 8.0.0, we now use WKWebView to implement Ti.UI.WebView (as Apple has deprecated UIWebView). 
https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView

Comment: And depending of the content: just use native elements, not a webview

Answer (score 1):

The path used by the url property when referring to local web content is relative to your project's Resources directory for Titanium projects, or app/assets and app/lib directories for Alloy project.

[Using Local Web Content with WebView](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/The_WebView_Component-section-src-29004918_TheWebViewComponent-UsingLocalWebContentwithWebView)